# Solution to share files over a WLAN between OS X and Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, wireless-networking, nfs

I search for a stable and efficient method to share files (ideally, via a filesystem mount, so I could listen to music and do backups without too much hustle) on a Linux server via WiFi with a Macbook. Some time ago I managed to connect two Linux laptops via NFS, but it was sloppy and slow. Is there anything more efficient out there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a mixed Mac/Windows/Android household, I use SAMBA daemon to share directories on the Linux box seamlessly to all clients.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/install.html

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/305771-quick-and-dirty-samba-setup

Answer (score 3):

Samba is certainly one way to go and allows Windows clients to browse as well.

You can also setup AFP (Apple File Protocol) on your Linux box.  OSX supports this natively so you get the same experience as connecting to another Mac on your network.  My "experience" (highly subjective) is that AFP seems faster than SMB especially since Mountain Lion/Mavericks.

Here's a simple walk through on setting up AFP on your linux box,  from http://straightedgelinux.com/blog/howto/afp.html:

---

As root, install netatalk

```
aptitude install netatalk
```

Setup afpd.conf

```
emacs -nw /etc/netatalk/afpd.conf
```

Most of this file consists of comments about how to configure AFP. The line that matters is this:

```
- -tcp -noddp -uamlist uams_dhx.so,uams_dhx2.so -nosavepassword
```

Create a directory that will be the shared location

```
useradd -m macshare
```

Next, modify /etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default

```
emacs -nw /etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default
```

And make it look pretty much exactly like this:

```
:DEFAULT: options:upriv,usedots /home/macshare macshare 
allow:instructor,student,admin,staff,klaatu,bob,carol,alice
options:upriv,usedots dperm:0777 fperm:0220
```

I habitually commandeer the floppy group and make it the group that has a more admin-y access to the shared directory. You do not have to do that; you can make your own group.

```
usermod -G floppy macshare
usermod -G floppy admin
```

Now chown the /home/macshare folder and also set its UNIX permissions

```
chown -R macshare:floppy /home/machshare
chmod 775 /home/macshare
```

Now set some defaults, which debian places in /etc/defaults. The important part is what netatalk runs when it is started up:

```
ATALKD_RUN=no
PAPD_RUN=no TIMELORD_RUN=no
A2BOOT_RUN=no
CNID_METAD_RUN=yes
AFPD_RUN=yes
```

Restart netatalk to instantiate the changes.

```
/etc/init.d/netatalk restart
```

Your users should now be able to log in remotely.